# I want to create a rails route that has no controller stipulated in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I am looking to create a route to a controller but I want to not have the name of that controller stipulated in the URL.

So the url would be something like this.
www.blabla.com/about_us.html

I don't want a about_us controller, instead I want a MainController and a about_us action.

I've read the routes from the inside out, but none of the instances indicated how to do this.

Does anyone know how to match a controller-less route to a specific controller?

Comment: I am curious why you would want this, a suggestion may be to add match routes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "path": option

```
resources :main, path: "/", only: [] do
  get :about_us
end
```

Now, all actions in main controller will be accessed directly without controller name in url
eg: localhost:3000/about_us

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of something similar in the Routing guide:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes

`get 'exit', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :logout`

You could use:

`get 'about_us', to: 'main#about_us'`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
resources :main,:path => '',:only => []
```

Now all actions of MainController can be accessed without controller name main in the url.

Comment: @baash05 it is working for me in case of restful routes. How ever you can also use `match "about_us" => "main#about_us",:as => "about_us"`. You can use `about_us_path` in your views.

Answer (score 0):

I settled on this...

```
MainController.action_methods.each{ |a| a = a.to_s; match a => 'main#'+a}
```

Private actions are not accessible, but all others are

Answer (score 0):

match 'about_us', :to => 'MainController#about_us'